# Create new variable in R based on certain values 2 years in a row

Tags: r, filtering

I am trying to use the UCDP Battle-related Deaths Dataset, called BattleDeaths_v22_1_conf from https://ucdp.uu.se/downloads/ (See under UCDP Battle-Related Deaths Dataset version 23.1)

I want to create a new variable or dataset that only includes countries with 1000 battle-related deaths 2 years in a row - and only after 2008.
However, I end up with a variable with no observations.

I used the dataset's  'country' variable (location_id) and the battle-death variable (bd_best).

So far I have done this in R:

```
library(dplyr)

filtered_data <- subset(BattleDeaths_v22_1_conf), bd_best >= 1000 & year >= 2008)

filtered_data <- filtered_data %>%
     arrange(location_inc, year) %>%
     group_by(location_inc) %>%
     mutate(sum_deaths_two_years = lag(bd_best) + bd_best)
```

So far so good.

```
final_data <- filtered_data %>%
      group_by(location_inc) %>%
      filter(all(sum_deaths_two_years >= 2000))
```

Now I end up with a variable with 0 observations. However, I can see in the original dataset, that there are observations that fit my criteria.

Ideally I would also like to have a separate variable where countries are included if they have 1000 battle-related deaths one year AND at least 25 battle-related deaths the previous or the following year.
But I have no idea how to use R for it, and any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Where can we find `BattleDeaths_v22_1_conf` - is it a dataset that is in R or an R package?

Comment: It is a dataset:) I downloaded it from https://ucdp.uu.se/downloads/

Comment: Thanks! Could you edit your question to include it as reproducible code, (i.e., `dput(BattleDeaths_v22_1_conf)`?

Comment: The data at your link appears to be 23.1, but your variable name suggests 22.1, not sure if that'll break things; further, is it the "dyadic" or "conflict" data?

Comment: @r2evans I have used the "conflict data". Yes, when I download it from https://ucdp.uu.se/downloads/ it says version 23.1 in the title, but the downloaded dataset is titled 22.1

Comment: @jpsmith Yes, of course - done!

Comment: Could you clarify your desired output? You state, "only includes countries with 1000 battle-related deaths 2 years in a row - and only after 2008." Is it only countries with *exactly* two years in a row? What if a country had 1100, 1200, 800, 900, 1200, 1500 deaths for years 2010-2015. What would you want the output be in this case?

Comment: @jpsmith 
Yes, I only wish to include countries that have 1000deaths one year and then 1000deaths the year right after. So 1000deaths exactly two years in a row. 

Next step for me is to create another variable where countries are included if they have 1000deaths one year and between 25-1000deaths the year before or after the year with 1000deaths.

Comment: @jpsmith ideally, I would like to create a variable, that includes countries countries with 1000 battle-related deaths exactly two years in a row AND countries that experience 1000 battle-related deaths one year and between 25-1000 battle-related deaths the previous or the following year.

Comment: Maria, jpsmith's mention to use `dput(.)` had nothing to do with inserting it into your code, it was to share the data. Notice that when you run `dput(head(BattleDeaths_v22_1_conf,10))` (for 10 rows of it), you get something that starts with `structure(...)`, please take ***that*** output and post into a [code block] so that we have a sample of your data. (While providing a link is often good enough, it is not uncommon for links in questions to go stale/bad, at which point the question is not-reproducible ... so embedded data is often better.)

Comment: @MariaMola, whenever someone asks for clarifications, suggesting the question is vague or incomplete, consider editing the question with the clarifications, rather than only explaining in the comments section.

Comment: In addition to links getting broken every now and then, as suggested by r2evans, see that people are often less motivated to look into the data if they have to download it from a link, so links will lead to less people willing to help. Always consider providing minimal datasets with `dput`

Answer (score 1):

This other solution using packages "data.table" and "magrittr" will give you the desired output

```
 library(data.table)
 library(magrittr)


 DT # your excel file 

 # Put the excel tab as a data.table, select filter columns and rename them
 DT %>% setDT() %>% .[,(Country = location_inc , year , Deaths = bd_best] %>%

 .[Deaths>=1000 & year>= 2008] %>% # we filter using desired conditions 


  # we add a columns containing for each row the years where the country is present                     in the table
  .[, YD := year %>% unique %>% toString , by = Country] %>% 

  # we now look if there are consecutive years in this list of years for each country
  .[as.character(Year+1) %in% YD] %>% 

  # we select the countries respecting this conditions
    .[, .(Country = unique(Country))] %>% 

  # we display the output
  .[] }
```

if you want to keep the 3 columns (country, Deaths and year) do not use the line selecting only the column country.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)

# Data ------------------------------
example_df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~location_inc,  ~year, ~bd_best,
  "Iraq",  2009L,    1036L,
  "Iraq",  2010L,     989L,
  "Iraq",  2011L,     864L,
  "Iraq",  2012L,     565L,
  "Iraq",  2013L,    1870L, # Desired
  "Iraq",  2014L,   13761L, # Desired
  "Iraq",  2015L,   10981L, # Desired
  "Iraq",  2016L,    9775L, # Desired
  "Iraq",  2017L,   10025L, # Desired
  "Iraq",  2018L,     866L,
  "Iraq",  2019L,     498L,
  "Iraq",  2020L,     671L,
  "Iraq",  2021L,     707L,
  "Iraq",  2022L,     335L,
  "Sudan", 2009L,     353L,
  "Sudan", 2010L,    1010L, # Desired
  "Sudan", 2011L,    1404L, # Desired
  "Sudan", 2012L,    1173L, # Desired
  "Sudan", 2013L,     594L,
  "Sudan", 2014L,     856L,
  "Sudan", 2015L,    1264L, # Desired
  "Sudan", 2016L,    1309L, # Desired
  "Sudan", 2017L,     160L,
  "Sudan", 2018L,     243L,
  "Sudan", 2020L,      45L,
  "Sudan", 2021L,      31L,
  "Sudan", 2022L,      47L)

# Code ------------------------------
example_df <- filter(
  example_df, 
  .by = location_inc,
  bd_best >= 1000, 
  lag(bd_best, default = -1) >= 1000 | lead(bd_best, default = -1) >= 1000)

# Outcome ---------------------------
example_df

# A tibble: 10 × 3
   location_inc  year bd_best
   <chr>        <int>   <int>
 1 Iraq          2013    1870
 2 Iraq          2014   13761
 3 Iraq          2015   10981
 4 Iraq          2016    9775
 5 Iraq          2017   10025
 6 Sudan         2010    1010
 7 Sudan         2011    1404
 8 Sudan         2012    1173
 9 Sudan         2015    1264
10 Sudan         2016    1309
```

Source: https://ucdp.uu.se/downloads/brd/ucdp-brd-dyadic-231-xlsx.zip